# New mod option 'Show DMCA locks' leads to 404 page

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderator-tools, 404-not-found, copyright-infringement

There's a new option in the moderator menu for posts: Show DMCA locks. However, when I submit that option, it takes me to a page that 404s: https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/279492/dmca. That is to be expected, as that's something that staff handles, not us, but it's better to not show that option altogether.

[image]

Comment: On a side note, wouldn't it be more appropriate to return a 403 in this case? As Glorfindel is clearly logged-in, the page clearly exists, but he is not authorized to access it.

Comment: @Luuklag actually that's a rare case of consistency in SE: they return 404 Not Found for anything one can't access, be it deleted questions, deleted profiles, etc. Many times (e.g. deleted questions) it exists and some can see it, but those who can't get 404 Not Found rather than 403 Forbidden.

Comment: [Is it OK to give status 404 to unauthorized users?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/82399/53036)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This option is, indeed, only supposed to be shown to employees. It'll be hidden from site moderators again starting with the next production build.

Thanks for the report!